# How to retrieve the Int between quotes from NSDictionary

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I call from an API which sends back the following response which I retrieve as NSDictionary:

```
{

UKUS = "1.2962";

USUK = "0.779689";

}
```

How can I get the first number out?

Comment: There is no order in a dictionary, so there is no "first". Which number do you want? The one associated with the key UKUS?

Comment: @Sweeper yes the first number, Thanks

Comment: `yourDict["UKUS"]`?

Comment: @Sweeper thanks this works, however, as there could be a combination of any two currencies, not just GBP and USD, is there a better way I could approach this issue? thanks.

Comment: “How to retrieve the Int ...”. First, these values are strings, so you’d have to convert them to numeric types. Or, better, if you have the ability to change to your web service, it should be fixed to return numeric types, not text strings. Second, surely you don’t mean `Int`, but rather perhaps `Double`?

Comment: Then how do you know which number to get? Note that the "first" value is not defined for a dictionary. You could do `dict.values.first` but that will not always be the same value.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper @Rob 
yourDict["UKUS"] has done the trick, I can now assign input values depending on choice to then combine two country codes in a string such as: 

    `code` yourDict["\(country1)\(country2)"]

Comment: You really shouldn’t have structure that is a dictionary whose keys can be any random value. (You can, but it’s not prudent.) It’s better to have a web service that has array of dictionary whose keys are fixed (e.g. `{"from": "USD", "to": "GBP", "buy_rate": 0.779689, "sell_rate": 1.2962}`. Use whatever key names you want, but make them consistent (which has benefit that you can abandon this `NSDictionary` approach). And the numeric values are actually numeric values rather than strings. Then your feed would be an array of these consistently-keyed objects.

Comment: Needless to say, I’d suggest shifting from country codes to currency codes, too.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot convert to Int but can convert it to Double

```
var myDictionary = ["UKUS":"1.2962","USUK":"0.779689"]

var myDouble = 0.0

//String to Double
myDouble = Double(myDictionary["UKUS"]!)!

print("myDouble:",myDouble)
```

Comment: That’s a little bold of you to use forced unwrapping operators, particularly from a feed from a remote source...